# ASP.NET MVC5 - Subir vídeo a YouTube a un solo canal

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

estoy realizando una plataforma en la cual se pueda subir un vídeo a la cuenta de YouTube, pero lo que quiero es que se suba A UN CANAL ESPECIFICO, por ejemplo mi canal. No quiero que el usuario logeado mediante oAuth2 suba el vídeo a su canal, sino, todos los usuarios independientemente si estan logeados o no, suban su video a mi canal. Tengo mucha confusión con Auth2, la API de Youtube y el nuevo código. Intenté esto pero me da error Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404. Gracias

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Title,Description,URL")] Post post, System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
                    YouTubeRequestSettings settings;
                    YouTubeRequest request;
                    string devkey = "mykey";
                    string username = "mymail@gmail.com";
                    string password = "mypass";
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Videos"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
                    settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Clave de API 1", devkey, username, password) { Timeout = 999999999 };
                    request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
                    Video video = new Video();
                    video.Title = fileName;
                    video.Description = "Sample Video Description";
                    video.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Comedy", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
                    video.Keywords = "Comedy";
                    video.Private = false;
                    video.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(filepath, "video/");
                    Video createdVideo = request.Upload(video); 
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(post);
    }
```

**Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404**

Comment: Hola Juan: ¡qué bien que lo solucionaras! Nótese que lo indicado es que escribas en una respuesta lo que resolvió tu problema. Lee por ejemplo [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](/help/self-answer).

Comment: que libreria usas para subir el video ? si intentas ejecutar este mismo codigo pero desde uan aplicacio de prueba en winform puedes hacerlo? o sea una aplicacion desktop subir un video de prueba usando este mismo codigo

Comment: esta claro que si usas con la clase YouTubeRequestSettings las credenciales de tu cuenta sera alli donde se suban los videos

Comment: @fedorqui gracias, ahi he publicado la respuesta con la solucion :)

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Justamente tampoco, no se podia desde la consola ni winform pero el codigo que he publicado sirve para ambas cosas, en fin. Una pregunta, nadie puede logearse y subir un vídeo en mi aplicacion, todos los vídeos se suben a mi canal, estas personas serán de diferentes partes del mundo, entonces mi pregunta es: ¿YouTube me bloqueará la cuenta si muchas personas de diferentes partes del mundo (diferentes IP's) suben vídeos a mi propio canal mediante mi aplicación? formulé la pregunta en el foro de Youtube pero me han enviado aqui. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Publico el codigo de la solucion, YouTube ha cambiado todo y desde ahora solo se puede usar esa API mediante OAuth2, hay que obtener un RefreshToken que lo obtuve desde aqui [StackOverFlow - Youtube api single user scenario with oauth uploading videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850287/youtube-api-single-user-scenario-with-oauth-uploading-videos/8876027#8876027)

Entonces, a continuación dejo el codigo de mi controlador completo, no olvidar cambiar las credenciales.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using testify.Models;
using testify.Clases;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace testify.Controllers
{
    public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        private TestifyContext db = new TestifyContext();
        private string UploadVideoId;


    // GET: Posts
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Posts.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Posts/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(post);
    }

    // GET: Posts/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Posts/Create
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Title,Description,videoId")] Post post, System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            UserCredential credential;
            var token = new TokenResponse
            {

                RefreshToken = "insertarRefreshToken"
            };
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = new UserCredential(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes = new[]
                {
                    YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload
                },
                }), "user",
                token);
            }
            // create service
            var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "test_app"
            });

            //objeto del video
            var video = new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = post.Title;
            video.Snippet.Description = post.Description;
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2", "Jesucristo" };
            video.Snippet.DefaultAudioLanguage = "es";
            video.Snippet.DefaultLanguage = "es";
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";


            //subida del video

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Videos"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(path);

            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(filepath);
            using (Stream stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                VideosResource.InsertMediaUpload insertRequest = service.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet, status", stream, "video/*");
                insertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
                insertRequest.Upload();
            }
            // return Content(UploadVideoId);



            //obtener el id del video

            post.videoId = UploadVideoId;

            //idVideoPost.videoId = video.Id;

            db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;



            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(post);
    }
    void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
        // string.Format("{0}", video.Id);
        UploadVideoId = video.Id;
    }

    // GET: Posts/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(post);
    }

    // POST: Posts/Edit/5
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PostId,Title,Description,videoId")] Post post)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(post);
    }

    // GET: Posts/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(post);
    }

    // POST: Posts/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        db.Posts.Remove(post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}